# Out-of-box membership provider for asp.net

Tags: asp.net, membership-provider

Is there any out-of-box membership provider for ASP.NET?

Or is there any tutorial for creating one?

My problem is that I can't do any change to ASP.NET membership and I need some change on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any out-of-box membership provider for asp.net?

Yes, there's the [`default membership provider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6e9y4s5t%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which uses SQL database. If you want to write a custom one you could inherit from the [`MembershipProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.aspx) class and implement the abstract methods you intend to use.

For example:

```
public class MyProvider: MembershipProvider
{
    ... implement the abstract methods here
}
```

and then in your web.config replace the default provider with your own:

```
<membership defaultProvider="Myprovider">
    <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="MyProvider" type="MyNamespace.MyProvider, MyAssembly" />
    </providers>
</membership>
```

Here's an [`article on MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which explains the different methods of the membership provider that you need to implement and what are they used for.

Comment: by **out-of-box membership provider** I mean not the **default membership provider**. and I want tutorial for details that I need to used

Comment: The only built-in membership provider is the default one. If it doesn't suit your requirements you will have to roll your own by inheriting from the MembershipProvider class as explained in my answer. There are many tutorials out there. Here's one for example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165159/Custom-Membership-Providers